# sed: Grabbing and replacing all data between last backslash and a comma

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have data in a csv format that looks like this:

```
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:39:25,N/A,C:\windows\system32\netsh.exe,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:24:02,N/A,C:\Windows\System32\networkexplorer.dll,N/A,False
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:38:53,N/A,C:\windows\system32\scrnsave.scr,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:25:10,N/A,C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WISPTIS.EXE,N/A,True
F1309-042543,05/03/14 22:05:42,N/A,C:\windows\ccmcache\4t\SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.009.exe,N/A,True
```

How can I go into the fourth field (the Windows path) and grab the process name (the final '\' character until the subsequent comma), and add that process name as its own field, separated by a comma? The end result would look like this:

```
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:39:25,N/A,C:\windows\system32\netsh.exe,netsh.exe,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:24:02,N/A,C:\Windows\System32\networkexplorer.dll,networkexplorer.dll,N/A,False
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:38:53,N/A,C:\windows\system32\scrnsave.scr,scrnsave.scr,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:25:10,N/A,C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WISPTIS.EXE,WISPTIS.EXE,N/A,True
F1309-042543,05/03/14 22:05:42,N/A,C:\windows\ccmcache\4t\SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.exe,SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.exe,N/A,True
```

In short, I want to take the process name out of that windows path and make it its own field in the CSV. I have a suspicion that sed is the tool to do this but I am not sure how to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247); have you considered using `awk` instead e.g. `awk -F, '{n=split($4,a,"\\"); $4=$4","a[n]}1' OFS=, file.csv`

Comment: @roaima apologies, I mean to say last backslash.

Comment: @steeldriver I had not considered using awk as I am unfamiliar with its usage. I appreciate your suggestion and will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not 100% clearly for me because your expected results are looking identical to the file contents, but let me give a try.

If you want only the file name in this list:

```
cat thebigfile.csv | rev | cut -d'\' -f1 | rev | cut -d',' -f1
```

The result will be:

```
netsh.exe
networkexplorer.dll
scrnsave.scr
WISPTIS.EXE
SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.exe
```

This helps?

Comment: I *think* the OP wanted to paste that in as as additional column into the not-entirely-unlike-CSV file, perhaps using `paste`, but I otherwise agree with your answer :-)

Comment: I think it will be better if he gives to us some example? I am adding a example of the substitution he wants, but i am not good with substitution and regex!

Comment: per the second code-block there, it's identical to the first but with the file-names added in a new column

Comment: I appreciate for selecting my answer as the right answer, but i think the other answer is the right answer...

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*\\\([^,]*,\)/&\1/' file
```

Output:

```
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:39:25,N/A,C:\windows\system32\netsh.exe,netsh.exe,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:24:02,N/A,C:\Windows\System32\networkexplorer.dll,networkexplorer.dll,N/A,False
F1309-042543,07/14/09 01:38:53,N/A,C:\windows\system32\scrnsave.scr,scrnsave.scr,N/A,True
F1309-042543,11/21/10 03:25:10,N/A,C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WISPTIS.EXE,WISPTIS.EXE,N/A,True
F1309-042543,05/03/14 22:05:42,N/A,C:\windows\ccmcache\4t\SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.009.exe,SafeNet High Assurance Client (x64) 2.12.009.exe,N/A,True
```

BTW, be aware of `^M` instead of `\n` in your original file.

Comment: What '&' here means?

Comment: @Putnik `&` match the whole previously selected pattern.